# How to increase sample rate of wav file and keep speech normal?

Tags: ruby, wav

I'd like to increase the sample rate of a wav file using the ruby wavefile gem, but keep the voices in the wav file sounding normal.   Basically this example, but modified so voices sound normal.
https://github.com/jstrait/wavefile/wiki/WaveFile-Tutorial#copying-a-wave-file-to-different-format

```
require 'wavefile'
include WaveFile

SAMPLES_PER_BUFFER = 4096

Writer.new("copy.wav", Format.new(:stereo, :pcm_16, 44100) do |writer|
  Reader.new("original.wav").each_buffer(SAMPLES_PER_BUFFER) do |buffer|
    writer.write(buffer)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a wav file as a collection of data points that are sampled at the given rate (the sample rate).  If you have a given collection at a known sample rate and you wish to increase the resolution of samples per unit of time, then you will either need to take new samples (i.e. make a new original recording at the desired rate) or extrapolate/approximate the necessary samples at the new data points that would appear between the ones you already have.

For example, if you have a recording at 22khz and you want to increase it to 44khz, then one option is to simply take each data point and repeat it once so you wind up with something like the following:

```

Original waveform samples over time:

1.2.3.4.5.6

if you only change sample rate:
123456 (same sound in half the time)

new waveform samples over time:

112233445566

```